# Javascript - Calculate user's age from user's form input

Tags: javascript

When a user enters their date of birth in a form as DDMMYYYY, how can I grab that and convert it into years to tell them their age?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to work with the `Date` object to get the age:

```js
var dateOfBirth = new Date(2010, 6, 17);
var today = new Date();

var diff = new Date(today.getTime() - dateOfBirth.getTime());

alert("Age: " + Number(diff.getUTCFullYear() - 1970) + " years, " + diff.getUTCMonth() + " months, " + Number(diff.getUTCDate() - 1) + " days");
```

Readup: [`Date` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)